# mysql search across joined fields

Tags: mysql, search

I have customer table with fileds for first name and last name plus other details.

In a form a user can enter a search which I have working but on unique fiels only eg searches for john in any of first name or last name. This all works ok

However I dont know how to search if a user enters john smith which would be a combination of two fields. How can I do this search with my current data structure?

Ive tried adding a field in the select statement using:

```
Concat_ws (' ', firstname, lastname) as fullname
```

But I cant use where on this generated field and throws an error

Should I create a new field to contain full name?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use aliases in where condition. instead use the complete function

e.g.

```
where Concat_ws(' ', firstname, lastname) like '%<your search>%'
```

But, yes, it is good idea to create a new field to optimize performance

And make sure you dont have space after the function name

Comment: Thank you.  I had the syntax wrong as you say for the coast column.  Works now in the correct place.  I'll look into thefull text option as well.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which combinations of fields you want. For your example `firstname = 'john' AND lastname='smith'` would do the job, but its probably not what you need.

The best solution would be to use a [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Thank you.  I'll research the full text search as well